# Is second expression of || skipped if first expression is true in c++?

Tags: c++

```
int found = 0, count = 5;
if (!found || --count == 0)
    cout << "danger" << endl;
    cout << "count = " << count << endl;
```

Expected output is `danger`, `count = 4` 
Why count isn't decremented by one?